# How to represent an integer with a float format of k-bit exponent and n-bit fraction?

Tags: floating-point, integer, representation

In *Computer Systems A Programmer's Perspective* (2ed), there's an exercise question that has been boggling my mind a lot these days. The exercise requirements are as follows:

2.84 ◆
Given a floating-point format with a k-bit exponent and an n-bit fraction, write
formulas for the exponent E, significand M, the fraction f , and the value V for
the quantities that follow. In addition, describe the bit representation.
A. The number 7.0
B. The largest odd integer that can be represented exactly
C. The reciprocal of the smallest positive normalized value

Although I'm clear about the format of float numbers, I'm not aware of what mathematical relationship there is between k and n to meet the requirements B and C above. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I assume the context is IEEE-754 floating-point formats. If so, [C] seems more straightforward than [B]. You know that an exponent field value of 0 indicates subnormal operand or zero. So the smallest biased exponent for a normalized operand is 1. What's the smallest fraction value? This gives you the " smallest positive normalized value". Compute its reciprocal. By construction of the IEEE-754 formats, we know it will be a representable floating-point number. Encode it. For [B], consider that all bits of the integer must fit into the mantissa (i.e hidden integer bit plus fraction bits).

Comment: As with infuriatingly many questions of this type on StackOverflow, there's not enough information here. Just giving the number of bits used in the exponent and the number of bits used in the fraction doesn't even get close to completely describing a floating-point format. Heck, we don't even know whether this is a *binary* floating-point format at this point. If you know that the question is about an IEEE 754-style binary floating-point format, please add that information to the question. If you don't know, then you need to find out, or give a lot more information about the format.